# (Python) Minimax Connect 4 Algorithm Not Blocking Player Moves

Tags: python, python-3.x, minimax

(Connect 4 is a game where you drop circles and try to create 4 connected circles of your color in either vertical, horizontal, or diagonal form.)

I'm building a connect 4 minimax algorithm, and it fails to prevent a loss, but seemingly only strives to win. It only attempts to connect its own pieces while not stopping me from connecting mine.

Algorithm: (X is Player, O is Computer)

```
def minimax(board, depth, is_maximizing, depthLimit):
    if detect(board, ' O '):
        return 100 - depth
    elif detect(board, ' X '):
        if is_maximizing:
            return 100 - depth
        else:
            return -100
    elif boardFull(board):
        return 0
    elif depth == depthLimit + 1:
        return 0

    if is_maximizing:
        max_eval = float('-inf')
        for row in range(6):
            for column in range(7):
                if board[row][column] == '   ' and not isColumnFull(board, column):
                    board[row][column] = ' O '
                    eval = minimax(board, depth + 1, False, depthLimit)
                    board[row][column] = '   '
                    max_eval = max(max_eval, eval)
        return max_eval
    else:
        min_eval = float('inf')
        for row in range(6):
            for column in range(7):
                if board[row][column] == '   ' and not isColumnFull(board, column):
                    board[row][column] = ' X '
                    eval = minimax(board, depth + 1, True, depthLimit)
                    board[row][column] = '   '
                    min_eval = min(min_eval, eval)
        return min_eval

def isColumnFull(board, column):
    for row in range(6):
        if board[row][column] == '   ':
            return False
    return True

def computerMove(board):
    best_score = float('-inf')
    best_move = None
    
    for row in range(6):
        for column in range(7):
            print(f'{round(((row/6)*100)+(column/7)*10, 2)}% Done Calculating')
            if board[row][column] == '   ' and not isColumnFull(board, column):
                board[row][column] = ' O '
                score = minimax(board, 0, False, depth)
                board[row][column] = '   '
                if score > best_score:
                    best_score = score
                    best_move = column

    for row in range(6):
        if board[row][best_move] != '   ':
            board[row - 1][best_move] = ' O '
            break
        elif row == 5:
            board[row][best_move] = ' O '
            break

    if detect(board, ' O '):
        print('O Wins!')
        return False
    return True
```

'board' is essentially a matrix containing the, well, board:
`board = [['   ' for i in range(7)] for f in range(6)]`

Example:
[image: As you can see, the minimax algorithm had a very unambiguous way of preventing its loss here.]

I've also ruled out the `detect()` function being buggy, as it works fine for detecting a win. (`detect()` essentially checks if there are 4 connected pieces of the same color/player)

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but it's kind of strange that computerMove calls minimax when it finds an empty space, even if there's no solid piece beneath it that would make it a legal move.

Comment: Does `detect` return True if there was a win?  Shouldn't a win by `O` always be the maximum negative, and a win by `X` always be maximum positive?

Comment: `detect` does return true if there was a win. Yes a win by `O` should be the maximum negative, and vice versa, which is why we return `100 - depth`/`-100` The `- depth` is just there to incentivize a faster win.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking X was the computer player.

Comment: If we just experimentally placed an X in a winning spot, you call `minmax(True)`, which will see that X wins and return a big number (100-depth), making it the preferred move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem looks to be here.

```
def minimax(board, depth, is_maximizing, depthLimit):
    if detect(board, ' O '):
        return 100 - depth
    elif detect(board, ' X '):
        if is_maximizing:
            return 100 - depth
        else:
            return -100
```

If O wins, it always returns a large positive. If X wins, it returns a negative or a positive, depending on whose turn it is. If we're maximizing, then it is X's turn, so we return a large positive number. In other words, the AI is indifferent between O winning and X winning on X's turn.

The fix is to make X the opposite of O:

```
def minimax(board, depth, is_maximizing, depthLimit):
    if detect(board, ' O '):
        return 100 - depth
    elif detect(board, ' X '):
        return -100 + depth
```

After making this change, it can figure out how to block X from winning.